# How do I generate an xml output from standfordner classifier?

Tags: xml, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, information-extraction

I have used standfordNER classifier to classify text. 
Here is the code.

```
string docText = fileContent;
        string txt = "";
        var classified = Classifier.classifyToCharacterOffsets(docText).toArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < classified.Length; i++)
        {
            Triple triple = (Triple)classified[i];

            int second = Convert.ToInt32(triple.second().ToString());
            int third = Convert.ToInt32(triple.third().ToString());
            txt = txt + ('\t' + triple.first().ToString() + '\t' + docText.Substring(second, third - second));

            string s = Classifier.classifyWithInlineXML(txt);
            string s1 = Classifier.classifyToString(s, "xml", true);
            Panel1.GroupingText = s1;

        }


        Panel1.Visible = true;
```

and this is the out put:

```
LOCATION    Lanka LOCATION  colombo ORGANIZATION microsoft
```

But i need an out put in xml format like this

```
<LOCATION>  Lanka </LOCATION>   <LOCATION>colombo</LOCATION>    <ORGANIZATION> microsoft</ORGANIZATION>
```

In my code i have used ,

```
 string s = Classifier.classifyWithInlineXML(txt);
            string s1 = Classifier.classifyToString(s, "xml", true);
```

to get the xml ,but its not working. since i m new to this field please do a help for me to resolve this.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code should be helpful:

```
   String content = "...";
   String classifierPath = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
   AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> asc  = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(classifierPath);
   String result = asc.classifyWithInlineXML(content);
```